# Is there a bug in this Wikipedia Pollard rho code sample?

Tags: python, algorithm, prime-factoring

I was looking at the Pollard rho algorithm.

I was chasing a bug in my program, and this way I found
that the Python code sample in Wikipedia returns 25 for number=25.

Is this normal? Or is there a bug in this code sample?

I thought it was supposed to return a non-trivial factor i.e. 5.

```
from itertools import count
from math import gcd

number, x = 10403, 2

for cycle in count(1):
    y = x
    for i in range(2**cycle):
        x = (x*x + 1) % number
        factor = gcd(x-y, number)
        if factor > 1:
            print('factor is', factor)
            exit()
```

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard's_rho_algorithm#Python_code_sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm#Python_code_sample)

Comment: It is possible for Pollard-rho to return N when trying to factor N, especially for small numbers. When that happens you need to try a new polynomial.

Comment: But I thought it always returns a non-trivial factor unless number is prime. No?

Comment: Actually, I don't think Pollard-Rho can ever factor a square.

Comment: It does, it works for OK for 49 e.g., the very same code.

Comment: Ok let me think about how that is possible. Anyway, it may happen that by the time you have detected the cycle it has occurred for both prime factors. When that happens the gcd(x-y, N) =N. You can use a different cycle detector like Brent's algorithm that finds the cycle earlier, or you can switch polynomials.

Comment: That python example does look funny, I'll have to admit.

Comment: Yes, it looks funny. I don't know how trustworthy it is.

Comment: Seems this version also fails to get a non-trivial factor of 12997 and of 485, I think this code sample is quite buggy.

Comment: It kind of looks like Brent's version, but not quite. I'll check the wiki history and see when it was added.

Comment: The current version of the python code is due to an edit that occurred on Feb 20th. Here is the [last version of the page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm&oldid=940956683) before the python was changed. I can't be sure if the previous code was correct either.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I think I found the error. They should be modifying y too in the loop. The pseudo-code is clear on that. This code is total mess. No idea how people can post such things just like that. The loop should do: `x := g(x)`, `y := g(g(y))` Instead it fixes the first x and does some non-sense which lost me half a day.

Comment: I think they are doing Brent's cycle finding method, whereas the earlier pseudocode is for Floyd's cycle finding method.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk OK... I don't know. Could be. Thanks for trying to help.